# If без фигурных скобок

Tags: java

Есть два куска кода

Первый:

```
if(5 > 3)
{
    int a = 5;
}
```

И второй:

```
if(5 > 3)
    int a = 5;
```

Второй выдает ошибку. Java 1.7, Win7 x64. Объясните пожалуйста почему второй выдает ошибку?

Comment: А какую ошибку?

Comment: error '.class' expected

Comment: @dirtez,@VladD это всё верно, но одно "но" у if без скобок получается нет области видимости, поэтому объявление и тут же инициализация не проходит?

Comment: @Kerins_Sataier: Потому что в этом случае если код не пойдёт по `if`-ветке, что должно быть с переменной? Должна ли она быть доступной в том scope, где находится `if`, даже если выполнение пошло по `else`? Чем она должна быть инициализирована  в этом случае? Поскольку разработчики Java не нашли удовлетворительные ответы на эти вопросы, они не разрешили такое.

Comment: @VladD крутой довод, спасибо Влад!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для объявления переменной нужен scope. Во втором случае его нет.

Поместить переменную `a` во внешний scope компилятор не может, так как если `if`-ветка не выполнится, переменная не будет инициализирована.

Comment: спасибо! сколько про иФЫ знал, а это что-то новое :)

Comment: Пожалуйста!

Comment: То есть нельзя так?:
int a;
if(5>3)
  a = 5;

Comment: Kerins_Sataier: не-а: http://ideone.com/I6xLay

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за наглядные примеры по этому случаю. Однако не пойму в чем отличается по scope вариант if со скобками и без с тем же условием, что даёт true.

Comment: @VladD, просто @dirtez делал в if сразу и объявление и инициализацию и тут не понятно почему компилятор ругается в случае без скобок,если эта переменная по данному условию всегда будет создана,но не использована во внешней обл видимости к примеру в варианте со скобками:http://ideone.com/xqwT5B

Comment: @Kerins_Sataier,«Для объявления переменной нужен scope». Написал в первом сообщении @VladD.

Comment: @dirtez, какой scope тогда?

Comment: @Kerins_Sataier, Что, какой scope? scope, это область видимости, или по другому, область между двумя фигурными скобками {}. Всё что в ней, не видно во вне, но не наоборот. В данном случае этого самого scope оператор if не имеет, а как заявил @VladD, чтобы объявлять переменные, нужно чтобы они находились в каком-либо scope. 

Т.к уровень английского пока не дотягивает чтобы курить официальные доки, поверим @VladD'у на слово. Вот где-то здесь должно быть написано http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3

Comment: @dirtez, @Kerins_Sataier: угу, 6.3:

> The scope of a local variable declaration in a block ([§14.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4)) is the rest of the block in which the declaration appears, starting with its own initializer and including any further declarators to the right in the local variable declaration statement.

Про блок (который я ошибочно называл scope) [вот](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2):

    Block:
        { BlockStatements<sub>opt</sub> }